# How to keep JPanel at top of parent container at runtime?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I create a parent container onto which I place several `JPanel` objects, each containing several `JButton` objects.

I create the parent panel, add the `GridBagConstraints` then add each child panel to the parent:

```
final JPanel options = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        options.setBorder(new TitledBorder("Select Option"));
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc.weightx = 1.0;
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTH;

        options.add(findPanel, gbc);
        options.add(addPanel, gbc);
        options.add(changePanel, gbc);
        options.add(dropPanel, gbc);
        gbc.weighty = 1.0;
        options.add(new JPanel(), gbc);
```

With `options.add(new JPanel(), gbc);` used to take up the extra space under my wanted panels.  Works great....until I want to change the contents of the parent after user interaction:

```
partnoFai.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
                    options.remove(findPanel);
                    options.remove(addPanel);
                    options.remove(changePanel);
                    options.remove(dropPanel);
                    options.add(partnoFaiInp, gbc);
                    gbc.weighty = 1.0;
                    options.add(new JPanel(), gbc);
                    frame.pack();
                    frame.validate();
                } 
            } );
```

It's adding the new panel, `options.add(partnoFaiInp, gbc);` to the middle of the parent when I want it at the top.  Why wouldn't `gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraint.NORTH;` keep the new panel in the `NORTH` of the panel?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You could place the "filler" component at a `gridy` position WAY below anything you might need (100 for example) or you could use [`add(Component, Object, int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#add(java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object,%20int)) to specify the index location of where you want the component added within the heirarcy

Comment: *"Why wouldn't gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraint.NORTH; keep the new panel in the NORTH of the panel?"* It is, the problem is, the "filler" panel is no been laid out before any of the other components because `add` does just that, it "adds" the component to the end of the containers list of components

Comment: I'm not understanding, so the "filler" panel should be added before the content panel?

Comment: It doesn't matter.  When you first setup the `options` panel, you add a `JPanel` to the last position, which you're using to "push" the content to the top of the `options` panel, which is fine.  But when you remove all the panels, the "filler" panel will move up and become both the first and last component on the container's component list.  When you add the `partnoFaiInp` panel, it is added AFTER the "filler" in the container's component list, so when the `options` are laid out, the filler panel is laid out first and THEN the `partnoFaiInp` and THEN the second "filler" panel...

Comment: Which puts the `partnoFaiInp` in the middle. You don't need the second "filler" panel, you just need to insert the `partnoFaiInp` panel before the first `filler`

Comment: Ok, so I removed the second "filler" panel from my `ActionListener` and changed the addition of the new panel to `.add(partnoFaiInp, gbc, 1);` but it's still being added to the middle of the `options` panel.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).

Comment: @corporateWhore Java is generally `0` indexed

Comment: @corporateWhore, you may try using `CardLayout`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to think of the `Container` in terms of a stack

When you first setup the panel using...

```
options.add(findPanel, gbc);
options.add(addPanel, gbc);
options.add(changePanel, gbc);
options.add(dropPanel, gbc);
gbc.weighty = 1.0;
options.add(new JPanel(), gbc);
```

The container has a list of components looking like `{findPanel, addPanel, changePanel, dropPanel, JPanel}`

When you remove the components using something like...

```
options.remove(findPanel);
options.remove(addPanel);
options.remove(changePanel);
options.remove(dropPanel);
```

The container now has a list of components looking like `{JPanel}`

Then when you add your new component using...

```
options.add(partnoFaiInp, gbc);
gbc.weighty = 1.0;
options.add(new JPanel(), gbc);
```

The container now has a list of components looking like `{JPanel, partnoFaiInp, JPanel}`

So, instead of adding the another "filler" component, you could just specify the insert point of the panel when you add it...

```
options.add(partnoFaiInp, gbc, 0);
frame.pack();
frame.validate();
```

The container now has a list of components looking like `{partnoFaiInp, JPanel}`

Comment: I was using -1 as bottom, 0 as center, and 1 as top...needless to say I was misguided.  `.add(partnoFaiInp, gbc, 0);` places the child `JPanel` object at the top of the parent.  Thank you so much for the help.

Comment: There are other options.  You could look at the `VerticalLayout` from SwingLabs, SwingX library or maybe even use a `CardLayout` ([How to Use CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html)), but there's not enough context to the question to make an appropriate suggestion

Comment: I've been intimidated by `CardLayout` in the past, I need to get the basic operation of this application done then I can go into making it look better with some proper layout managers.  Thanks for your time.